# Calculate azimuth between points

Tags: qgis, point, csv, direction, azimuth

I have a points from file in CSV format containing the following fields:

[image]

I want after ordering the points based on collecting time, to calculate the direction in degrees between the points.
[image]

From point 1 to point 2, from point 2 to point 3, etc.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your items are already sorted by time, `Id` can be used as the ordering reference.

Go to your layer's Attributes Table and create a new Field with the `Field Calculator`, using this formula:

```
azimuth($geometry,geometry(get_feature(@layer_name,'Id',"Id"+1)))*180/pi()
```

It computes the azimuth (in degrees) between the current point (`Id`) and the point which has `Id+1` in the layer.

[image]

You can then for instance use the Azimuth field to rotate arrows indicating the next point:

[image]